# Two content providers accessing same database/table sample implementation

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

My question is similar to [Two content providers accessing the very same database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842218/two-content-providers-accessing-the-very-same-database), but I've few more questions around it:

1. Can two content providers from two different application access the same table. Say, I've database "db1" and table "names" under it created by CP1. Now, I want CP2 from another application able to detect if "db1/names" exist. If it does, then read from it and update value or so on, otherwise create one.
2. If above is possible, then where can I look at for implementation related sample code ?

Comment: what do you have problems with? what have you done so far?

Comment: Right now, CP1 and CP2 are creating their own databases and tables. I'm not sure how can I feed data from both CPs into one database?

Comment: use SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase()

Comment: I got the sample code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053809/share-sqlite-database-between-2-android-apps. But it requires to know the context of the another app. Is it possible to share database without knowing (independent of) the context of other app? May be not :(

Comment: context? what context do you mean?

Comment: "android.content.Context"

Comment: why not just to use SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase()?